# Can't assign admin type to my create admin command

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to create a command that will generate a new admin account. The command will ask for some details. I want to give that new account the type field of admin but i'm getting error that my type field doesn't have a default value. What is wrong with it?

**Code**

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
    const DEFAULT_TYPE = 'default';

    public function isAdmin() {

        return $this->type === self::ADMIN_TYPE;
    }
}
```

**Create:admin**

```
public function handle()
{
    $name = $this->ask('What is your full name?');
    $username = $this->ask('What is your username? (this will be your display name)');
    $email = $this->ask('What is your email?');
    $country= $this->ask('Where do you live? (country)');
    $password = $this->secret('Choose a password');

    User::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'username' => $username,
        'email' => $email ,
        'password' => Hash::make($password),
        'country' => $country,
        'type' => User::ADMIN_TYPE,
        'participated' => false,
    ]);
}
```

**Register controller for normal users**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    session()->flash('success', 'You have successfully created an account!');
    $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'participated' => false,
                'type' => User::DEFAULT_TYPE,  
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'country' => $data['country']
    ]);

    Score::create(['user_id' => $user->id]);

    return $user;
}
```

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'type' doesn't have a default value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your user class to be like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    const ADMIN_TYPE = 'admin';
    const DEFAULT_TYPE = 'default';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'participated', 'type', 'country'
    ];

    public function isAdmin() {

        return $this->type === self::ADMIN_TYPE;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I made a really silly mistake, I forgot to add the type property to fillable. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help @dax

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced these issues before and normally it will be a whitelisted error from the fillable property in the user model. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment for more details.

If you already whitelisted **type**, dump User::DEFAULT_TYPE.